# Does confluent cloud allow custom connector deployment

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

1. Confluent cloud supports only following connector.

   - GCS Sink Connector
   - S3 Sink Connector 
     Please validate If my understanding is correct or not.
2. Can we deploy custom connector or cdc like debezium in confluent cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More connectors are always being added to Confluent Cloud as part of its managed service.

If you want to run other connectors than those available with Confluent Cloud you currently need to run the Kafka Connect workers yourself. You can use these with Confluent Cloud.

Comment: Hi @Robin Thanks for the response. I am working on a project where we extensively using connector. We dont yet have the access to confluent cloud. I did a qucik check and found out there is confluent CLI and web access. To Deploy connector worker manually we will need the connector node access. Can you point me to a document where it shows how can we deploy connector manually in confluent cloud.

Comment: You can't. Per my answer, if you need run a connector that is not available in Confluent Cloud then you will have to operate the Kafka Connect workers yourself.